# Where did Bluetooth hardware factory reset move to in Ventura?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, restart

Whilst struggling with [iMac M1 forgets it has a TouchID key](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459317/imac-m1-forgets-it-has-a-touchid-key) I discovered [Reset Mac OS X Bluetooth service?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13763/reset-mac-os-x-bluetooth-service) which shows a useful way to reset not just the Bluetooth service from within the Mac, but also a method, by holding  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  whilst opening the Bluetooth menu, to reset associated hardware to factory conditions.

[image] [image]

Unfortunately, this useful debug menu is gone in recent macOS, to be replaced by this simplified version.

[image]

**Does anyone know where it went?**
Prior to it being in this menu, it was in the Xcode toolkit. I don't have or use Xcode to be able to quickly find it if this is where it's gone, but I'm quite willing to download/install necessary parts if that's what's required.

Comment: Didn't it just restart `bluetoothd` ? You can try `sudo pkill bluetoothd` in Terminal

Comment: There are two different commands in that debug, reset bluetooth & factory reset all connected devices. I know resetting bluetooth works temporarily, same as rebooting the Mac, I want to see what the full hardware reset can do.