# How to reset Apple Magic Keyboard to factory defaults

Tags: keyboard, imac, restart

I have an [Apple Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english). And after last update of my iMac 2017 27" to Ventura 13.4.1 (c) the number keys on the second from top row of the keyboard have stopped working. Additionally, the left Control key is also not functioning. But number keys from the numeric keypad (on right side) work well.

After I connected my keyboard to MBP that I use for work the problem is still here. So I think that something bad was set up to keyboard on my iMac and so factory reset can help me.

I tried all the "solutions" for my problem that I found in the internet, but nothing helped me :-(

Apple support didn't help too. They recommended that I take the keyboard for repairs to the nearest service center.

Comment: There is no factory reset for a keyboard and no driver will affect keys in the manner you describe. It’s likely a hardware failure.  Given that a whole row of keys failed, something happened to the electrical trace/circuit for those keys.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298853/119271) for a teardown of a keyboard.  Your best bet is to replace the keyboard

Comment: Last chance saloon - plug it into USB, just for final confirmation it's broken. They work just as well [if not actually better] on USB. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459317/85275 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459591/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks, I actually tried this. And it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the comment, but the "+" and "-" keys on the diagram in your response are not located right after "0" in the connection scheme, and the Ctrl key as well. It looks strange that all these keys stopped working simultaneously. I still tend to think that it was related to the recent OS update.

Comment: I think that its bug can be related only to keyboards extended with numeric keypads  and so not so popular :-(

Comment: The diagram you saw is just a representation, but all keyboards work the same way, the traces are arranged in a matrix pattern.   When you press a key it sends a “scan code” that the OS translates.  In other words, you aren’t sending letters or symbols, but hex values.  There’s no driver update that will suddenly start ignoring these hex values it receives.