# Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad (A1843): Bluetooth not working anymore

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad (A1843, version 1.6.0 according to the information in the Bluetooth settings), which I used wirelessly on several Macs without any problems, until from one day to the next it could no longer be connected to the Macs via Bluetooth -- connecting it directly via cable, however, was still no problem. Since it continued to charge, I'm guessing it's not a faulty battery. Since unpairing made no difference, I would have liked to reset the keyboard to factory settings as a next step. This used to be possible via the Bluetooth menu, but unfortunately this has not been available since Mojave (?). Is there any other way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Existing question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/462116/119271